# REGEX replace by template words list (NPP)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text in file like:

```
"Complete Storage Facility within 1:05 on Easy difficulty or harder without any marines dying."
"Complete Storage Facility within 1:05 on Normal difficulty or harder without any marines dying."
```

How to replace it to

```
"Пройдите Storage Facility за 1:05 на лёгком или более высоком уровне сложности без потерь в отряде."
"Пройдите Storage Facility за 1:05 на среднем или более высоком уровне сложности без потерь в отряде."
```

PS: `лёгком` mean `Easy`, `среднем` mean `Normal`, `1:05` and `Storage Facility` is dynamic values.

Comment: This looks like Greek to me, or maybe Russian, but in any case, you can just try doing a find and replacement for each term you want to change from English.

Comment: (Yeah, Russian.) No, I need to do not translate for 3-5 lines, its about 100 lines with that template `Complete .* within .* on .* difficulty or harder without any marines dying.`

Comment: There is a logical problem here.  The words `Easy` or `Normal` might occur in any sentence, and each has a different translation.  Just these two words might require two largely separate regex.  You should sort out your translation needs.

Comment: I'm just said 'by template'?

Comment: There is no something like "if (/1 == normal) { text_for_normal }"?

Comment: Two ideas: 1. use google translate and see what comes out. 2. search and replace in several steps (i.e. each word/part that you want to translate in its own).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Notepad++, find:

```
Complete (.*?) within (.*?) on (?:(easy)|(normal)) difficulty or harder without any marines dying
```

replace:

```
Пройдите \1 за \2 на (?3лёгком)(?4среднем) или более высоком уровне сложности без потерь в отряде.
```

Comment: `(?3лёгком)(?4среднем)` ... how does your regex know whether it matched `easy` or `normal`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html

Comment: I had no idea this was possible +1 ... definitely worth studying in Notepad++.